# Does every function have a value of 0 for the nth derivative?

Tags: calculus

Just out of curiosity, and for no other reason then I've been staring at the ceiling wondering, does every function have a value of zero at the nth derivative? And if it does, is there a function that can be used to tell you at which derivative the value of the function is zero?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=e^x$.

Comment: Or, for that matter, $g(x) = \sin x$ or $h(x) = \cos x$

Comment: true, well I guess that answers this question

Comment: looks like I need to re-think how I ask this one

Comment: with these comments, is there an infinite set of functions which would not have zero as a derivative?

Comment: For some reason, I'm reminded of [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) on MO.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator: Ad the last comment, $x \mapsto ae^x$ for $a \not=0$ gives you an infinite family of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact, any smooth function (one that can be differentiated arbitrarily many times) which is not a polynomial is such an example. This is a result of the following:

**Theorem:** Let $f(x)$ be a $n$-times differentiable. If $f^{(n)}\equiv 0$ (meaning $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x$) then $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

**Proof:** $$f(x)=\int\cdots\iiint f^{(n)} = \int\cdots \iint C_0=\int\cdots\int (C_0x+C_1)=\cdots=C_0x^{n-1}+\cdots+C_{n-1}$$

Comment: @user1551 The OP asks whether the function has **a value of zero**, not **a zero**. I interpreted this as being zero everywhere, but I think it is unclear.

Comment: @AlexBecker that is correct, I did mean zero not a zero, I see I poorly stated my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions whose derivatives are non-zero including $e^x$, $\sin(x)$ (whose derivatives have roots but are not simply $0$) or even just $\frac{1}{x}$